# Remote Development for .Net Technologies

Tags: .net, remote-access, remote-debugging

i am .Net developer and run software house as a small team i want to make a environment where all my team members work together on the same project online like i am doing work on a single class at the same time my friends work on the second class in same project. can anyone helps me how to config that type of development environment

Answer (score 0):

absolutely use TFS (Team Foundation Server)

[TFS Overview](https://www.visualstudio.com/tr-tr/products/tfs-overview-vs.aspx)

This is TFS hosted on Azure it's free http://tfspreview.com/

If you need more info about TFSPreview, read this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/09/14/team-foundation-server-on-windows-azure.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The Hosted version of TFS is now known as [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs) (VSTS), formerly Visual Studio Online (VSO).

It provides 5 free Basic licenses and any MSDN subscribers in your company are also free apart from these.

VSTS includes

- Version / source control in Git or TFSVC
- Issue, work and project tracking using Kanban/Scrum/Agile templates
- Build and release management systems (60 mins free every month)
- Extensible add-ons to enable integration or advanced testing via addons from Marketplace